# How to get list of months javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get the list of months in javascript! how can I get this done by using only javascript!

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean by `months`? what is the expected format?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: You mean, like, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`? Or you want something shorter?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I only need a list of month names!

Comment: @DimalChandrasiri you mean, like, `['January', 'February', ..., 'December']`?

Comment: or, is the question whether such array is already hard-coded somewhere in the core Javascript?

Comment: I've wrote an automatic month list generator : https://gist.github.com/yairEO/39822cc583d833457f6e

Comment: Here is the code inline:        var months = [];
      for (var m = i = 1; i <= 12; m = ++i) {
        date = new Date(`${m}/1/2009`);
        months.push(date.toLocaleString('en-us', {
          month: 'long'
        }));
      }

Comment: To follow @PeteAlvin's lead:  const MONTHSOFYEAR = [...Array(12).keys()].map(m => new Date(2017, m, 1).toLocaleDateString(navigator.language, { month: 'long' }));

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Since you should be using [moment](http://momentjs.com/) to deal with dates anyway, you might as well use it here too! ;)

[`moment.months()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/) or [`moment.monthsShort()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/) (both added in 2.3.0):

```
const moment = require('moment');
moment.locale('en'); // sets words language (optional if current locale is to be used)
moment.months() // returns a list of months in the current locale (January, February, etc.)
moment.monthsShort() // returns abbreviated month names (Jan, Feb, etc.)
```

Comment: moment().lang()._months

Comment: `moment.months()` - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/listing-months-weekdays/

Comment: I like you solution because moment has localization!

Comment: If you're using `lodash` or `underscore`, this simply becomes: `var months = _.times(12).map(i => moment().month(i).format("MMMM"))`. No need to initialize `count` or `months`.

Comment: thanks @TimMedora -- that months method was added in 2.3.0 in October 2013 -- I'll update the answer (a bit late) for future visitors

Comment: From the docs: 2.16.0 deprecated using moment().months(). Use moment().month() instead.

Comment: @DmitryShvedov `month()` returns the month for a moment in time, not a list of localized months

Comment: @Andbdrew see for yourself: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/

Comment: @DmitryShvedov the doc you linked says that the `month` method is used to get or set a month for a specific moment instance -- it doesn't return a list of months

Comment: @Andbdrew it's `months` that gets deprecated not `month`. See the note at the bottom of the section!!!

Comment: @DmitryShvedov I think you've found some buggy/confusing docs (and an opportunity for github fame)! The output of `moment().month()` is a number, not a list of month names -- https://jsfiddle.net/dcobLjzh/ the changelog for 2.16 doesn't mention deprecating months https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @Andbdrew I think everything will become clear if you actually READ my comment and the docs that I sent you, which are official moment.js docs. Yes, `moment().month()` is fine.

Comment: Don't get confused with `moment().months()` vs `moment.months()`, as I did. :) 
`moment().month()` indeed returns the index of the current month (zero based).

Answer (score 54):

As far as I know, you can only get the array by hard-coding it.

```
var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
```

Or you can use some javascript library which has this list hard-coded.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak You're right, i just show an example.

Comment: a bad example is worse than no example at all.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I downvoted, not you. For the reason stated above.

Comment: @WesleyMurch if you upvote, I'll summon a downvote squad from the javascript room. This is a bad way of creating a new array.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak You should post an answer to get enought information to OP, thank ;)

Comment: @RongNK I _hope_ (wish) OP is already aware of the option of hard-coding the array and is just asking if there's another way. I don't think there is a better way than this. However, I'm also wondering if this question is worth keeping.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think OP want to know where javascript(or jquery) hard-coded like java,...

Comment: Thank @Jan Dvorak for editing !

Comment: You can get all months with js now: `const months = [...Array(11).keys()].map(key => new Date(0, key).toLocaleString('en', { month: 'long' }))`.

Comment: @Jonathan That should be `Array(12)`, not 11, but correct modern answer. I've just edited this question and requested it be reopened, you should submit that as an answer if so.

Comment: As a TypeScript enum: `enum MONTHS {
  JANUARY = 0,
  FEBRUARY = 1,
  MARCH = 2,
  APRIL = 3,
  MAY = 4,
  JUNE = 5,
  JULY = 6,
  AUGUST = 7,
  SEPTEMBER = 8,
  OCTOBER = 9,
  NOVEMBER = 10,
  DECEMBER = 11,
}`

Answer (score -5):

Please use this one:

If you want to get the current month:

```
var theMonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var today = new Date();
var aMonth = today.getMonth();
var i;
for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
  document.write(theMonths[aMonth]);
  aMonth++;
  if (aMonth > 11) {
  aMonth = 0;
}
```

If you want to get all months:

```
var theMonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May",
  "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
  document.write(theMonths[i]);
}
```

Comment: who is down the vote please explain here what is wrong in this code

Comment: Please explain here what is wrong

Comment: Please don't use `new Array`. Use an array literal. The former has a special case when passed a single number. It also looks bad. Please don't use `document.write` or `document.writeln`. It can't be used anytime except when the page is still loading and should be avoided. Also, it's better to avoid `<br>`.

Comment: So give then right answer if you know what is right

Comment: Umm..., RongNK's answer is the best I can give, sorry. No need to duplicate his. Also, writing an answer does not prevent me from downvoting the other bad answers.

Comment: you know array is list of the element "<br>" just for write the content in page

Comment: I do. However, it's still better to avoid it - I downvoted for the other two reasons, however. Also, your formatting is broken (I can fix that, but I can't fix the content).

Comment: you know what is the best answer If know then give the answer

Comment: You have the edit formatting permission right

Comment: I can fix the formatting (hold on), but my downvote will stay. Fixing the content would change the meaning of the answer - that's not what editing is for.